# Rviz markers with rospy

Tags: ros, python, rviz, rospy, marker

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to visually represent a "robot" as a sphere marker from the visualization_msgs, but I am unable to publish my self.robotMarker.  When I rosrun this script I am able to see the message from the print statement, however when I rostopic echo /robotMarker, my node crashes.  Am I initializing my Marker() correctly?  Any help is appreciated.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import rospy
from std_msgs.msg import String
from geometry_msgs.msg import PointStamped
from visualization_msgs.msg import Marker

_ACTIONS = [('N', [0,-1]),('E', [-1,0]),('S',[0,1]),('W',[1,0]),('NE',[-1,-1]),('NW',[1,-1]),('SE',[-1,1]),('SW',[1,1]), ('STAY',[0,0])]
_X = 0
_Y = 1

class stateNode():

def __init__(self):
    pub = rospy.Publisher('state', PointStamped, queue_size=10)
    markerPub = rospy.Publisher('robotMarker', Marker, queue_size=10)
    rospy.Subscriber("action", String, self.move_callback)

    rospy.init_node('stateNode', anonymous=True)

    rate = rospy.Rate(1)
    self.state = PointStamped()

    # initial starting location I might want to move to the param list
    self.h = rospy.get_param("height", 100)
    self.w = rospy.get_param("width", 100)
    self.state.point.x = self.h
    self.state.point.y = self.w
    self.state.point.z = 0

    self.robotMarker = Marker()
    self.robotMarker.header.frame_id = "/Cmap"
    self.robotMarker.header.stamp    = rospy.get_rostime()
    self.robotMarker.ns = "robot"
    self.robotMarker.id = 0
    self.robotMarker.type = 2 # sphere
    self.robotMarker.action = 0
    self.robotMarker.pose.position = self.state.point
    self.robotMarker.pose.orientation.x = 0
    self.robotMarker.pose.orientation.y = 0
    self.robotMarker.pose.orientation.z = 0
    self.robotMarker.pose.orientation.w = 1.0
    self.robotMarker.scale.x = 1.0
    self.robotMarker.scale.y = 1.0
    self.robotMarker.scale.z = 1.0

    self.robotMarker.color.r = 0.0
    self.robotMarker.color.g = 1.0
    self.robotMarker.color.b = 0.0
    self.robotMarker.color.a = 1.0

    self.robotMarker.lifetime = 0

    while not rospy.is_shutdown():
        pub.publish(self.state)
        markerPub.publish(self.robotMarker)
        print "sending marker", self.robotMarker
        rate.sleep()

def move_callback(self, action):
    for i in _ACTIONS:
        if String(i[0]) == action:

            self.state.point.x = self.state.point.x + i[1][_X]
            self.state.point.y = self.state.point.y + i[1][_Y]

            if self.state.point.x>self.h:
                self.state.point.x = self.h
            if self.state.point.y>self.w:
                self.state.point.y = self.w

            self.state.point.z = 0
            self.robotMarker.pose.position = self.state.point
            # print i
            print self.state.point.x, self.state.point.y

stateNode()
```

This is what my terminal screen gives me:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jbourne/catkin_ws/src/plume_localization/scripts/stateNode.py", line 77, in <module>
    stateNode()
  File "/home/jbourne/catkin_ws/src/plume_localization/scripts/stateNode.py", line 56, in __init__
    markerPub.publish(self.robotMarker)
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/topics.py", line 852, in publish
    self.impl.publish(data)
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/topics.py", line 1036, in publish
    serialize_message(b, self.seq, message)
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/msg.py", line 152, in serialize_message
    msg.serialize(b)
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/visualization_msgs/msg/_Marker.py", line 233, in serialize
    buff.write(_struct_3i10d4f2iB.pack(_x.id, _x.type, _x.action, _x.pose.position.x, _x.pose.position.y, _x.pose.position.z, _x.pose.orientation.x, _x.pose.orientation.y, _x.pose.orientation.z, _x.pose.orientation.w, _x.scale.x, _x.scale.y, _x.scale.z, _x.color.r, _x.color.g, _x.color.b, _x.color.a, _x.lifetime.secs, _x.lifetime.nsecs, _x.frame_locked))
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'secs'
[WARN] [WallTime: 1460512033.085431] Inbound TCP/IP connection failed: connection from sender terminated before handshake header received. 0 bytes were received. Please check sender for additional details.
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/231781/rviz-markers-with-rospy/) by [jbourne](https://answers.ros.org/users/23668/jbourne/) on ROS Answers with karma: 53 on 2016-04-12

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2016-04-12**:
Can you post the output from the "crash"?

**Comment by [jbourne](https://answers.ros.org/users/23668/jbourne/) on 2016-04-13**:
I am unable to upload the log file because of lack of points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The issue is on the following line from your original code:

```
self.robotMarker.lifetime = 0
```

If you look at the definition of a [visualization_msgs/Marker](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/visualization_msgs/html/msg/Marker.html) message, you'll see that the `lifetime` field is of type "duration" which is a built-in type that needs to be a `rospy.Duration` instance in Python (see [here](http://wiki.ros.org/msg#Fields)). In the line of code above, you are setting the value to an integer which is incorrect. That is what causes the

```
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'secs'
```

line in your output log.

**Edit**

You could change the line to something like

```
self.robotMarker.lifetime = rospy.Duration(0)
```

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2016-04-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jbourne](https://answers.ros.org/users/23668/jbourne/) on 2016-04-13**:
Thank you for the clarification.  Yes this seems to fix my bug.